# How to write query strings for API requests

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have found a weather API: [WeatherAPI.com](https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/)  And I want to fetch all the cities (apparently there is a location object). I am super new to all this and I found an example, which I tried to follow. However city is undefined. Which, I suppose is the reason for my API call not to return any json: `{"error":{"code":1006,"message":"No matching location found."}}`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
const city = req.query.city;
const getWeatherData = await fetch(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}&q=${city}&days=5&aqi=no&alerts=no`
  );
  const data = await getWeatherData.json();
  res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

How do I get cities into query string, is it even possible to list all the cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Request](https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/#intro-request) section I had to look for Search or Autocomplete request, so fetch URL should look like that:

```
https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/search.json?key=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}&q=${city}&days=5&aqi=no&alerts=no
```

search.json instead of forecast.json. Now it returns an empty array and I guess I can do the search in the input on front end.

Comment: If you are planning on hitting this search api on every keystroke in the input field, be aware of your API calls limits.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using this API, it doesn't seem that you can get the forecast info for all the cities at once. Quoting their docs on Forecast API: `Forecast object contains astronomy data, day weather forecast and hourly interval weather information for a given city.`. See the `given city` part, you need to give a valid city name to get the forecast info from this API.

You can maybe look for other APIs that offer that, here's 2 lists of many public APIs:

1. https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis
2. https://github.com/public-api-lists/public-api-lists

Comment: But I guess I can still use it for search and autocomplete, if I get it into my front end, right? See my answer below.